# What are the effects of a totally removed eponychium?

Tags: risks, removal, nails, epidermis

The eponychium (Cuticle) serves as a protective barrier between the epidermis and the nail. If this were to be removed, what are the effects and possible remedies?

Comment: I made your question less personal, as personal advice is off topic here. Please let me know if the change is unacceptable, and I can roll it back (Which would likely result in it being closed, however).

Comment: @JohnP thanks a lot for the help, you made a masterpiece with it!